# How to define PHP variable when playing SWF

Tags: php

I'm going to play SWF and when I use PHP (`src="uploads/<?php echo    $tab['banner']  ?>"`) it is not working. Can you tell me how to use php in here?
When I write  `src="uploads/223.swf"` it works OK.

My code is:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" height="350" width="235">
<param name="movie" value="uploads/<?php echo $tab['banner']  ?>">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode">
<embed wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" src="uploads/<?php echo    $tab['banner']  ?>" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="350" width="235">
</object>
```

Comment: what does `$tab['banner']` echo out ? As in what's the output.

Comment: Is your database select code all okay? Might be worth posting some code that is relevant to it

Comment: yes it prints 223.swf from database

Comment: So what's the problem then if it prints it?

Comment: view source code output in your browser to see what's actually printed

Comment: hi thanks for comment. i have found the fault. many thanks

Answer (score -3):

You can simply replace

`value="uploads/<?php echo $tab['banner']  ?>"` to

```
value="<?php echo 'uploads/'.$tab['banner'] ?>"
```

You can try using this code

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" height="350" width="235">
<param name="movie" value="<?php echo 'uploads/'.$tab['banner']  ?>">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode">
<embed wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" src="<?php echo 'uploads/'.$tab['banner']  ?>" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="350" width="235">
    </object>
```

Comment: That doesn’t change anything; it just needlessly outputs a static part of content via PHP.